# Passing in multiple attributes when using Stand alone validators in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm wanting to use a [standalone validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#standalone-validators) in `Yii2` but I'm not sure how pass multiple attributes in when overiding the [validateAttributes()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#validateAttributes%28%29-detail).

Here is an example of my validator:

```
class RegistrationValidator extends Validator {

    public function validateAttributes($model, $attributes = null) {

    }

}
```

Here is how I am calling it from within the `rules()` method inside my model:

```
[['username','email'], RegistrationValidator::className()],
```

However when doing a `var_dump` inside the validator on the `attributes` variable I seem to have *all* the attribute names, not just username & email.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are saying that you need attribute names not value?

Answer (score 0):

You have overriden wrong method. You should override [validateAttribute($model, $attribute)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#validateAttribute%28%29-detail) instead of [validateAttributes($model, $attributes = null)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#validateAttributes%28%29-detail). At least this is the common way to do it.

You can access the attributes of the model with the parameter (as you have found out with `validateAttributes()`). However, you then have to decide which error messages the attributes should get. You can distinguish with the $attribute parameter. But you don't have to add errors to both attributes, although it could be reasonable.

Comment: Oh ok, I thought since I was passing in multiple values I should use that one.

Comment: Nope, just tested it and it only takes the first value of the array.

Comment: @Brett Ah... so it's the combination of the attributes you'd like to validate?

Comment: Yes. I needed to pass in two attributes, but after posting this I realized since I know what attributes I want I can then just reference them directly with `$model->attribute_name`; so not really a big deal ha

Comment: @Brett, Ok, I see. Then the answer has no use. Sorry for that.

Comment: No problems at all :)

Comment: Updated my post. Hope that helps anyone else a little bit.